# JavaScript AutoComplete does not narrow down results

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am able to fetch the complete list of items as I start typing but I am unable to see the results narrowed down as I continue to type.

JavaScript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jq(function autoCompleteDisease() {
    jq("#diseaseName").autocomplete({
        minLength: 2,
        source: function(request,response) {
            var results = [];
            jq.getJSON('${ ui.actionLink("getPlanNameSuggestions") }',
                {
                  'query': request.term, 
                })
            .success(function(data) {
                for (index in data) {
                    var item = data[index];
                    results.push(item.name);
                }
                response(results);
            })
           .error(function(xhr, status, err) {
                alert('AJAX error ' + err);
            });
        }
    })
});
</script>
```

HTML

```
<input id="diseaseName" name="diseaseName"/>
```

Could anyone please provide me suggestions..Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Issue fixed! Had missed a line in the controller .java file - fetching the results bas